# Trying to find the steady state temperature of air inside a semi-truck trailer?

Tags: heat-transfer

To start, this is mostly a procedural question, so I'll be doing some handwaving for the numbers.

Lets say I have a semi-truck trailer. It's insulated and refrigerated, and meant to transfer drink cans. I know the ambient air temperature outside (which I'll call $T_{amb}$), the solar irradiation on the truck $G_s$, and the speed of the air around the truck. On the inside, I'm give the speed of the air along the truck walls, the thickness of the insulation, and its thermal properties. I'm asked to first treat the temperature of the air as a steady state problem, assuming the effect of the air  on the coke is negligible to the temperature of the air.

My first instinct is to do any energy balance. I've got some irradiation from the sun coming in. Some of it will be reflective, some of it emitted, and some of it absorbed, which will be transferred to the insulation. (I have all of these properties). I've got some energy leaving from the external convection. I have a way to approximate this, but for both the energy emitted back as radiation and convection, I need the temperature of the outside of the trailer to calculate an actual heat transfer rate, not to mention to calculate a $h$ for the convection. If we assume that the trailer has thin walls, than I need the outer temperature of the insulation $T_{sO}$

The net heat transfer is conducted through the insulation, resulting in some interior surface temperature $T_{sI}$. I can use this to calculate a interior air temperature along with my refrigeration, which is a constant that I know. Even though I don't know my air temperature, and thus my heat transfer coefficient, I can use solution iteration to find it.

As it stands, I have one equation with two variables: the Interior air temperature and the exterior insulation temperature. Is there another equation I can formulate? Am I approaching this problem wrong? Is there any assumptions that will remove one of these variables?

Any help would be appreciated. Sorry if this is confusing, this is my first post.

Comment: You have exterior air temp, this is all you need.  Convective heat transfer will only ever give the fluid temp, not the insulation temp.  This is just a forced convection problem.  You'll also have to make assumptions about sun angles.

Comment: Is there a way you would approach this problem? Not asking for an answer, but how would you go about setting it up?

Comment: It's just a heat flux balance.  At some interior temp, the heat removed by the refrigeration system unit will equal the heat gain from forced convection and sunlight radiation.

Comment: And just to be clear when you say forced convection you mean convection on the outside?    The problem I'm having right now is that to come up with h values for the interior and exterior convection, I need to assume some film temperatures.

Comment: yes. forced convection of plates through parallel and perpendicular flow.  Don't make it complicated, find the empirical forced convection formulae.

Comment: draw a network diagram, using the "resistor" analogy . . .